# query is not working with DATE_FORMAT

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select  d.doctorFName,d.doctorLName ,count(ap.appointmentID) totalap,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  s.speciality) specialities
FROM  tbl_doctors d
INNER JOIN  tbl_doctor_speciality  ds ON (d.doctorID = ds.doctorID)
INNER JOIN tbl_speciality  s ON (s.spID = ds.spID)
Inner join tbl_appointment ap on (ap.doctorID = d.doctorID)
Inner join tbl_patients p on p.patientID = ap.patientID 
GROUP BY d.doctorID
where d.status = 1 and  DATE_FORMAT(ap.appDate, '%Y-%m') = '2013-10'
```

my below query is giving me error  after where i am doing wrong please help me?

```
where d.status = 1 and  DATE_FORMAT(ap.appDate, '%Y-%m') = '2013-10'
```

**error**

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where d.status = 1 and ds.spID and DATE_FORMAT(ap.appDate, '%Y-%m') = '2013-10' at line 9
```

Comment: Does it work without DATE_FORMATE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` clause is in the wrong place. It goes before the `group by`:

```
select d.doctorFName,d.doctorLName ,count(ap.appointmentID) totalap,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  s.speciality) specialities
FROM  tbl_doctors d
INNER JOIN  tbl_doctor_speciality  ds ON (d.doctorID = ds.doctorID)
INNER JOIN tbl_speciality  s ON (s.spID = ds.spID)
Inner join tbl_appointment ap on (ap.doctorID = d.doctorID)
Inner join tbl_patients p on p.patientID = ap.patientID 
where d.status = 1 and  DATE_FORMAT(ap.appDate, '%Y-%m') = '2013-10'
GROUP BY d.doctorID;
```

Comment: its return single record after using above query,why?

Comment: is this possible fetch all the records if there DATE_FORMAT(ap.appDate, '%Y-%m') = '2013-10' is not return true then we return 0

Comment: @MuhammadRashid . . . I don't understand your last comment.  I think it might be more appropriate for another question, with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to interchange these two lines

```
where d.status = 1 and  DATE_FORMAT(ap.appDate, '%Y-%m') = '2013-10'
GROUP BY d.doctorID
```